Use Cellular Data while Maintaining Connection to Offline Wifi Hotspot
For a project I'm doing, I want to maintain a connection to an offline wifi hotspot. I want to do this so I can interact with the device wirelessly.
I want to also, at the same time, be able to use my phone to browse the internet.
So
Device A : 100% offline. Wifi Hotspot Emitting.
Device B : Phone. Connected to Wifi Hotspot. Use Cellular Data for internet.
Is this possible? I have the newest iPhone with the newest iOS if it helps. I have Wifi Assist turned on in Cellular Settings, but it seems that just puts you on Cellular when the Wifi internet is poor (thus killing my connection to Device A).

Is this a question about the iPhone having two connections, or about a computer connecting to two connections? If it is about an iPhone it is off topic on this site. If you're trying to connect a computer to two different wireless networks simultaneously, this is not a feature commonly found on computers, or supported in OSes.

I was sent here from SO Networking.  Where should I post it then?  Its about an iPhone being connected to the wifi of an offline hotspot, while still being able to use its cellular data for internet.  I want to be able to ping my offline hotspot for info, then be able to use that info online.

Sorry that you've gotten the run-around, but you were misinformed by Networking. There is an AskDifferent SE sister site for Apple-related questions. Superuser's rules state that questions about mobile devices are only on topic if they are interacting with a computer, and that computer is the main point of the question.

This would work you changed roles. Make Device A act as a Wi-Fi client instead of an AP, and have it join the mobile hotspot AP feature of the iPhone. You could also make this work if Device B was a Mac with a cell data adapter instead of an iPhone. Or if Device B was a Mac using the iPhone as its USB/Lightning-tethered cell data adapter.

It's easy to create an AP on your computer, so this question should really be "How can an iPhone use mobile data for internet but also connect to an AP without internet." Which is an Apple question, and out of scope here.
